# How to aggregate fields with null data and missing fields in elasticsearch?

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I have elasticsearch database as following:

```
   {
       "market": "NEW YORK",
       "hour_time_stamp": "2019-08-24 01:00:00",
       "model_year": 2014,
       "num_devices": 28   
   },
   {
       "market": "COLUMBIA",
       "hour_time_stamp": "2019-08-12 01:00:00",
       "model_year": 2019,
       "num_devices": 2    
   },
   {
       "market": null,
       "hour_time_stamp": "2019-08-11 01:00:00",
       "model_year": 2016,
       "num_devices": 1  
   },
   {
       "hour_time_stamp": "2019-08-02 01:00:00",
       "model_year": 2014,
       "num_devices": 750
   },
   {
       "market": "COLUMBIA",
       "hour_time_stamp": "2019-07-12 01:00:00",
       "model_year": 2018,
       "num_devices": 21
   }
```

As you can see, some values of market are null and in some cases the market field is missing. I have written the following elastic.js query to fetch the market and perform aggregation on it:

```
let queryBody = ejs.Request()
      .size(0)
      .query(
        ejs.BoolQuery()
          .must(
            ejs.RangeQuery('hour_time_stamp').gte(this.lastDeviceDate).lte(this.lastDeviceDate)
          )
      )
      .agg(ejs.TermsAggregation('market_agg').field('market').order('sum', 'desc').size(50000)
      .agg(ejs.SumAggregation('sum').field('num_devices'))        
      );
```

The data that I need is market name and sum of num_devices for that market(since market can be repeated). The query I have written returns only the market where market value is defined. I need to include the missing market as well as "market": null in my bucket. Any ideas how I can do that?

Comment: You need to add missing('N/A') to terms aggrgeation

Comment: That returns       .agg(ejs.TermsAggregation('market_agg').field('market').missing() is not a function

Comment: .missing('N/A')  pass parameter and check it should be working

Comment: Hi, there is no missing function in elastic.js
https://cdn.rawgit.com/ErwanPigneul/elastic.js/master/dist/docs/ejs.html

Comment: You have a ExistsFilter...